# New Scala.js facade for Three.js -> "Cannot find module "THREE""

Tags: three.js, scala.js, facade, transpiler, scalajs-bundler

As https://github.com/antonkulaga/threejs-facade is heavily outdated I tried an approach like: https://github.com/Katrix-/threejs-facade and would like to create a facade for the new `three.js` library.

I am by no means a `JS` expert, nor am I a `Scala.js` expert, so odds are I am doing something really dumb.

After another question I am using this `sbt-scalajs-bundler` and `sbt-web-scalajs-bundler`

My `build.sbt` looks like this:

```
lazy val client = (project in file("modules/client"))
  .enablePlugins(ScalaJSBundlerPlugin, ScalaJSWeb) // ScalaJSBundlerPlugin automatically enables ScalaJSPlugin
  .settings(generalSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    name := "client"
    //, scalaJSModuleKind := ModuleKind.CommonJSModule // ScalaJSBundlerPlugin implicitly sets moduleKind to CommonJSModule enables ScalaJSPlugin
   ,jsDependencies += ProvidedJS / "three.min.js"
  )

lazy val server = (project in file("modules/server"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala, WebScalaJSBundlerPlugin)
  .settings(generalSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    name := "server"
    ,scalaJSProjects := Seq(client)
    ,pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(scalaJSPipeline)
    //,pipelineStages := Seq(digest, gzip)
    ,compile in Compile := ((compile in Compile) dependsOn scalaJSPipeline).value
  )
```

`three.min.js` is in the resources-folder of my `client` project.

One part of the Facade is e.g.

```
@js.native
@JSImport("THREE", "Scene")
class Scene extends Object3D {
```

and I want to use it like this: `val scene = new Scene`. On `scala.js` side this actually compiles just fine, but when I run it I get:

> Error: Cannot find module "THREE"

in the browser and I wonder why. It's called like this in `three.min.js` after all.

Now I tried providing and serving the `three.min.js` file from the server side as well, because I thought that maybe it was just missing at runtime, but no, that does not seem to be the cause.

So now I wonder what am I doing wrong here?

Just to **clarify**: Rest of transpiled `js` works just fine, if I do not export any usage of the Facade!

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: https://scalacenter.github.io/scalajs-bundler/cookbook.html#global-namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this part](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/facade-types.html#a-nameimporta-imports-from-other-javascript-modules) of Scala.js documentation, `@JSImport` is interpreted by the compiler as a JavaScript module import.

When you use the `CommonJSModule` module kind (which is the case when you enable the `ScalaJSBundlerPlugin`), this import is translated into the following CommonJS import:

```
var Scene = require("THREE").Scene;
```

This annotation only tells how your Scala code will be interfaced with the JS world, but it tells nothing about how to *resolve* the dependency that provides the `THREE` module.

---

With scalajs-bundler you can define [how to resolve JS dependencies from the NPM registry](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalajs-bundler/reference.html#npm-dependencies) by adding the following setting to your `client` project:

```
npmDependencies += "three" -> "0.84.0"
```

(And note that you can’t use `jsDependencies` to resolve these modules with `@JSImport`)

Also, note that the correct CommonJS import to use three.js is `"three"` instead of `"THREE"`, so your `@JSImport` annotation should look like the following:

```
@JSImport("three", "Scene")
```

---

Alternatively, if you don’t want to resolve your dependencies from the NPM registry, you can supply your CommonJS module as a resource file. Just put it under the `src/main/resources/Scene.js` and refer to it in the `@JSImport` as follows:

```
@JSImport("./Scene", "Scene")
```

You can see a working example [here](https://github.com/scalacenter/scalajs-bundler/tree/v0.5.0/sbt-scalajs-bundler/src/sbt-test/sbt-scalajs-bundler/js-resources).

Comment: Thanks but I want to provide the js file myself